# Container show on all screens | flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to show the internet connection status on all the screens. If an internet connection is available, don't want to show the Container.

I used this `internet_connection_checker` package

My try:

- Set `bool hasInternet = false;`
- Created a function to get internet connection status:

  ```
  checkInternetConnection() {
    InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
      final hasStatus = status ==
          InternetConnectionStatus.connected; 
      setState(() => hasInternet = hasStatus);
    });
  }
  ```
- It set in `initState`
- and used `hasInternet ?` to show container like below coding

  ```
       hasInternet
                  ? const SizedBox()
                  : Container(
                      color: warningRed,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20, vertical: 3),
                      height: 25,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Center(
                        child: CustomText(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          size: 15,
                          text: "No internet connection",
                          textColor: whiteColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
  ```

If I use this method, I have to set this for all screens one by one. Have any solution for this?

Comment: You have to use a state management plugin, set a global variable, and then make a top-level ComponentsWidget. Put it in the outermost layer of all pages

Answer (score 0):

- you can use this demo.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyWidget());
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<NetWorkStatusProvider>(
            create: (context) => NetWorkStatusProvider(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(routes: {
          FirstScrren.routeName: (context) => const FirstScrren(),
          SecondScreen.routeName: (context) => const SecondScreen(),
        }, home: FirstScrren()));
  }
}

class BaseLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const BaseLayout({super.key, this.appBar, required this.child});
  final AppBar? appBar;
  final Widget child;
  @override
  State<BaseLayout> createState() => _BaseLayoutState();
}

Widget _notConnectedWidget(BuildContext context) {
  var appSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  var appPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
  return Container(
    height: appSize.height - appPadding.top,
    child: Center(
      child: Text('netWork Not Connected!'),
    ),
  );
}

class _BaseLayoutState extends State<BaseLayout> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<NetWorkStatusProvider>().checkInternetConnection();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: widget.appBar,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Selector<NetWorkStatusProvider, bool>(
            selector: (context, provider) => provider.isConnected,
            builder: (context, isConnedted, _) {
              return isConnedted ? widget.child : _notConnectedWidget(context);
            },
          ),
        )));
  }
}

class NetWorkStatusProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isConnected = true;
  void setIsConnected(bool val) {
    if (val != isConnected) {
      isConnected = val;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void checkInternetConnection() {
    InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
      setIsConnected(status == InternetConnectionStatus.connected);
    });
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static final String routeName = '/SecondScreen';

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var appPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
    return BaseLayout(
        child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: appSize.height - appPadding.top,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('SecondScreen'),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, FirstScrren.routeName),
              child: Text('go to FirstScrren'))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class FirstScrren extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScrren({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static final String routeName = '/FirstScrren';
  @override
  State<FirstScrren> createState() => _FirstScrrenState();
}

class _FirstScrrenState extends State<FirstScrren> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var appPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
    return BaseLayout(
        child: Container(
      height: appSize.height - appPadding.top,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('FirstScrren'),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, SecondScreen.routeName),
              child: Text('go to SecondScreen'))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```